# Split function to smaller ones

Tags: javascript

I have that function which gets data from API (`getFollowedArtistsAdapter`) until it's not the last page of results. I want to make it all as one Promise. But when I look at this function it seems to be illegible and unnecessarily convoluted.

```
const getArtists = () => {
  let afterGet = null;
  let items = [];

  return new Promise(function promiseCallback(resolve, reject) {
    const afterParam = afterGet ? {limit: 50, after: afterGet} : {limit: 50};

    getFollowedArtistsAdapter(afterParam)
      .then((data) => {
        items = items.concat(data.artists.items);

        if(data.artists.next){
          afterGet = data.artists.items[data.artists.items.length - 1].id;
          promiseCallback(resolve, reject);
        } else {
          return updateStoreArtists(items).then(() => resolve());
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Any ideas how to split it?

Comment: i don't think this code is convoluted *in terms of how it's laid out* but it might be a problem that you are updating outside variables in a promise.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just calling `getFollowedArtistsAdapter`, which `return`s a recursive call of itself (or `updateStoreArtists`) at the end, if needed, without creating an unnecessary new Promise:

```
const getArtists = () => {
  let items = [];
  return getFollowedArtistsAdapter({ limit: 50 })
    .then((data) => {
      const thisItems = data.artists.items;
      items = items.concat(thisItems);
      if (data.artists.next){
        const after = thisItems[thisItems.length - 1].id;
        return getFollowedArtistsAdapter({limit: 50, after });
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      return updateStoreArtists(items);
    });
}
```

This way, all `getFollowedArtistsAdapter` calls will be completed in the first `.then`. When the first `.then` resolves, `items` will be fully populated, and the second `.then` will return the Promise from `updateStoreArtists`.

Avoid the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803743/).

Comment: This is it. Thank you!